# How read the file using Common-lisp of Format Function?

Tags: common-lisp

this is myself write:

```
(defun test (x)
  (with-open-file (stream x :if-does-not-exist nil)
     (let ((read-line-1 (read-line stream))
          ((read-line-2 (read-line stream)))
       (format t "This is the test-1     ~s~%" read-line-1)
       (format t "This is the test-2     ~s~%" read-line-2))))
```

i just want know how read one file , thanks

Comment: what do you want: print (as in the question title) or read (as in the question)? It's unclear what you want to do and what your actual problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You have a basic typo in your code, you have an extra parenthesis around the binding for `read-line-2`. What you probably want is

```
   (let ((read-line-1 (read-line-stream))
         (read-line-2 (read-line-stream))) ...
```

If you enter the code you posted in an editor that auto-indents Lisp code according to the standard, you will see that your `format` lines actually are asking to bind a variable named format. And if you try to compile the code you posted, your compiler will likely complain that `(read-line-2 ...` is not a symbol.

If you fix that extra parenthesis, the second part of your problem might be that the argument x needs to be a "pathname designator", which you might not be correctly specifying for your implementation.

```
    (test-2 #P"/home/user/fammmm/foo.txt")
```

might be what you want.